# Port issue in compose file

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, sbt

I am getting port issue in docker compose.

My compose file is:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    hostname: postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  test:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    environment:
      DB_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

My docker file for test is

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-1.2.8.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-1.2.8.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-1.2.8.deb && \
  rm sbt-1.2.8.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

ENV WORK_DIR="/test"

USER root

COPY . ${WORK_DIR}/

RUN cd ${WORK_DIR} && \
    sbt test
```

While running it i am getting:

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**

TEST_DB_URL is an env variable in application.conf.

I am running the individual commands:

docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up db

It works fine and docker ps show

```
 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

But when i run docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up test i downloads dependencies and compiles the code and give me Connection to localhost:5432 refused.

Comment: Your error message has a different host name from the `TEST_DB_URL` environment variable setting (`postgres` vs. `localhost`).  Can you show the code or configuration that uses this variable?  Can you include the actual code that makes the database connection?

Comment: Added the snippet. @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has nothing to do with connecting to the database, but is a configuration issue. It's using the default from the `application.conf` instead of using the override from the environment. You could try to narrow it down by simply printing the config in Scala and figuring out why the `ConfigFactory` doesn't pick up the environment variable.

Comment: I have tried by passing explicity the URL at which the postgres run then also i get connection issue.